# Average, Instantaneous Change And Linear Approximation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-approximation

I have these 2 question:

1. A function f(x), is any function, so that
   $L_{a}(x)=L_{b}(x), a \not= b$. Show $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\frac{f'(b)+f'(a)}{2}$.
2. Assume that $a \not= b$ and that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\frac{f'(b)+f'(a)}{2}$, prove or disprove $L_{a}(x)=L_{b}(x)$.

For 1. I find that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\frac{f'(b)+f'(a)}{2}$ this is asking when the average rate of change is equal to the instantaneous rate of change, of a and b. But, that is all I find. How do I show this equation is true using this information?

For 2. I know $L_{a}(x)=f(a)$ and $L_{b}(x)=f(b)$. They are differentiable. at x=a, x=b, for f(x). I think, the linear approximation is a linear equation. And, a linear equation is a polynomial, so if $L_{a}(x)=L_{b}(x)$, then every term in the linear equation is equal.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What are $L_a,L_b$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net They are linear approximation of f(a) and f(b). But f(x) is random, so it depends on f(x)

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it I understand well $L_a(x)$ being the linear approximation of $f$ at $a$, we have

$$L_a(x) = f^\prime(a)(x-a) +f(a)$$

and in a similar way
$$L_b(x) = f^\prime(b)(x-b) +f(b).$$

If those two coincide, we have in particular
$$\begin{cases}
L_a(b)&=f(b)&=f^\prime(a)(b-a) +f(a)\\
L_b(a)&=f(a)&=f^\prime(b)(a-b) +f(b)
\end{cases}$$

From which we get the requested equality by substracting the two previous equations.

The converse is not true. For a counterexample, take $f(x)=x^2$ and $a=-b=1$. We have

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{a-b} = \frac{f^\prime(a)+f^\prime(b)}{2}=0$$ however the linear approximations are different.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you show how $L_a(b)=L_b(a)$ can make the equality $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\frac{f'(b)+f'(a)}{2}$?

Comment: It is straight forward when you write down the equation $L_a(b)=L_b(a)$.

Comment: Thanks. I entered your website too. It is a very good website.

Comment: Also sorry, but it is difficult to get $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\frac{f'(b)+f'(a)}{2}$. So if $L_{a}(b)=L_{b}(a)$, then $$f(a)+f'(a)(b-a)=f(b)+f'(b)(a-b)$$To expand this I get $f'(a)(b-a)-f'(b)(a-b)=f(b)-f(a)$. Then I get $f'(a)+f'(b)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$?? I can't get the 2 on the fraction. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Hi again. Sorry, I did a mistake in the answer that is now fixed.